# JavaFX Could not get function pointer for JLI_Launch

Tags: macos, javafx

I'm trying to build a native launcher for a JavaFX app on OSX using the standard JavaFX packaging tools. Nothing happens when I launch the app by double clicking / selecting it from the spotlight / etc...

When I go into the application bundle from the terminal and launch from `Contents/MacOS/APP_NAME` I see an error like:

```
2014-08-21 13:29:22.488 APP_NAME[4479:507] Could not get function pointer for JLI_Launch.: (
    0   CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c25b25c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib       0x00007fff84ebde75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8c25b10c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   APP_NAME              0x0000000107f5bde1 launch + 593
    4   APP_NAME              0x0000000107f5b366 main + 70
    5   APP_NAME              0x0000000107f5b314 start + 52
    6   ???                   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Environment Info:

```
$> java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)

$> sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9.4
BuildVersion:   13E28
```

Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

Comment: I have no idea what the cause of your specific issue is.  Why would you build your own native launcher for JavaFX, when such functionality is already included in by the [JavaFX packaging tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm)?  I guess if you really wanted to build your own, you could base it off the [official mac native launcher code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/5f6c2a2877d1/modules/fxpackager/src/main/native/launcher/mac/main.m).

Comment: No, I am using the official packaging tools already. Everything builds perfectly fine but then the resulting application doesn't launch.

Comment: Oh ok, I misunderstood. Thx for clarifying.  Please add your environment information to your question (OS version, JavaFX version and hardware description).

Answer (score 0):

I use MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 and i get "Could not get function pointer for JLI_Launch" error

I use CS6 Illustrator and had to install JAVA 6 (https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=es_MX) because Illustrator crashes with new JAVA version.

But having older version of JAVA caused jdownloader crash so i downloaded again jdownloader from this link http://jdownloader.org/download/index and choose "Version 10.6 or lower"   from this link: (spanish)

- Descargar Installer MacOS Version 10.6 or lower  (http://mega.nz/#!vd1yxZCS!n-W5tr_1LSlQiIaEaQFodPKzi938EwDLjsaiFsoproQ)

Now i have both java versions, older for ILLUSTRATOR and newest to jdownloader and other software

It helped me to solve this problem, hope it works to others